# Providing a subset of vector containing character strings as a text variable for rm_between_multiple() function from qdapRegex

Tags: r

I am trying to remove parts of multiple strings of characters located between certain signs (".1" and blank space in this instance) which are stored in subsequent rows of a vector from a data frame.
I need to perform this on a subset of rows which contain string of characters that lack a square bracket ("[").
Here is what I have tried:

```
library(qdapRegex)
library(data.table)

df$V1 <- rm_between_multiple(subset(df, df$V1 %like% "["), c(".1 "), c(" "), replacement = ".1"))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

"**Error in grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
TRE pattern compilation error 'Missing ']''**"

Is there a workaround to this problem?
Please advice.

Comment: a square bracket is a control character within a regular expression (i.e. it means something other than just the character `[`.  You need to escape it with a slash:  "\\["

Comment: I think you are right. I have noticed in the documentation that adding FIXED = TRUE to the rm_between_multipe() function should disregard "[" as regular expression special character and treat it like a typical character. Will try this out and update. @PaulStaffordAllen